# Running test Python script under Apache 2.4 gives error "end of script output before headers"

Tags: apache, apache2, python

I am trying to get a simple web service running on my local computer. In my `cgi-bin` directory in the `Apache24` folder I added an empty file called `pywps.cgi` with the following content

```
#!C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env\python.exe
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"C:/pywps")
import os
os.environ['PYWPS_CFG']='C:/pywps/pywps.cfg'
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR']='C:/ProgramData/Anaconda2/envs/wps_env/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data'
# Note that WPS runs as apache user and not as you, so many more user variables might be needed.
# Restart Apache after adding one.
import pywps
```

The main `index.html` file works fine, but when i try to open `http://localhost/cgi-bin/pywps.cgi` I get an error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log

I checked the error log and I've got this going on:

```
[Wed Sep 19 10:36:25.173859 2018] [core:notice] [pid 11404:tid 476] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Wed Sep 19 10:36:25.191859 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11404:tid 476] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8080
[Wed Sep 19 10:36:26.134859 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8080:tid 416] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Sep 19 10:36:27.134859 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1520:tid 420] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Sep 19 10:37:03.781859 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 8080:tid 976] [client ::1:54670] End of script output before headers: pywps.cgi
```

I have been looking all over for the `end of script output before headers` but I'm not sure what could be causing it. I checked and rechecked my `DocumentRoot` path and also the paths in the `cgi` file to no avail. Could anyone help please?

**EDIT**

I tried adding the following after setting the interpreter path:

```
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
```

Which seems to run the script with no issues but does not output the desired `xml`. Modifying the above `html` with `xml` throws an error:

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 1:
>   Extra content at the end of the document Below is a rendering of the
>   page up to the first error.

Where line 2 contains the additional `print` statement shown above.

Comment: Is this the appropriate place to ask questions about Apache? I see from this Meta post that there are perhaps more suitable locations --> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237189/where-to-ask-questions-about-apache-and-wamp

Comment: "Is this the appropriate place to ask questions about Apache?" - Your question isn't necessarily about "Apache" as such. It sounds like a general HTTP/web/CGI programming question. When coding a CGI script you need to make sure the necessary HTTP response headers are sent before the response _body_. It sounds like these have been omitted. Your second error implies the "XML" you are returning is invalid (an XML syntax issue, possibly due to erroneous characters in the output).